# predict() not recognizing a variable name from a fitted model

Tags: r, regression, lm, predict, metafor

Am I missing something that causes `predict.rma()` not to find `"factor(outcome)"`?

```
library(metafor)

dat <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/tst.csv")

fit <- rma.mv(d ~ factor(outcome)*time, V = SE^2, random= ~1|id, data = dat)

predict.rma(fit, addx=T, newmods = c("factor(outcome)"=1, time=1))

# Error: Could not find variable 'factor(outcome)' in the model.
```

Comment: Is there some reason not to use `dat$outcome <- factor(dat$outcome)` and convert the variable to a factor in `dat` so that the formula becomes `d ~ outcome*time`?

Comment: @dcarlson, the question is about `predict.rma()`. So, that doesn't make a difference. The data and example is fully reproducible, just tried it out to see it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems to work if you put in values for all 7 coefficients (except `intcpt`), e.g. `newmods = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)` for outcome=1, time=1 or `newmods = c(0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 16)` for outcome=4, time=4, but there should be a simpler way.

Comment: @dcarlson, I see I wish there was a way to automate this, like in [HERE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/plot_interactions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `time` has only 4 values and `outcome` has only 4 values, you can automate the process of generating the predictions for the 4 x 4 = 16 combinations pretty easily:

```
lvls <- 4   # for factor(outcome)
mat <- rbind(0, diag(lvls-1))
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    1    0
# [4,]    0    0    1
# Combinations of outcome * time
combos <- expand.grid(o=1:4, t=1:4)
vals <- t(with(combos, mapply(function(o, t) c(mat[o,], t, mat[o, ] * t), o, t)))
pvals <- predict.rma(fit, addx=TRUE, newmods = vals)
```

This gives the predicted values and confidence intervals for all combinations.

Comment: Thank you so much! What if the intercept was excluded like: `fit <- rma.mv(d ~ factor(outcome)*time-1, V = SE^2, random= ~1|id, data = dat)`?

Comment: It should be the same. We only provide values for the dependent variables. The intercept is a constant. You might contact the `metafor` package maintainer for suggestions.

Comment: I think we might have been wrong all along. Here is what the `metafor` author said in an email: *"If you want to obtain the predicted value for level 1 of the outcome factor when time = 1, you would use:

`predict(fit, addx=T, newmods = c(0,0,0, 1, 0,0,0))`

(the spaces in `c()` have no meaning, they are just there to make this easier to read)

For the other three levels, it would be:

`predict(fit, addx=T, newmods = c(1,0,0, 1, 1,0,0));
predict(fit, addx=T, newmods = c(0,1,0, 1, 0,1,0));
predict(fit, addx=T, newmods = c(0,0,1, 1, 0,0,1))`"*

Comment: That is exactly what we are doing. See my second comment  before the Answer or look at the `vals` object which puts all 16 combinations of outcome and time into a single matrix.